# Show Loading pinner on Filter Table based on Radio selected id from the Query

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement the best possible way to filter the table based on each radio selected. At the moment the filtering is working but I need to add a spinner to kind of show while the filtering of the data is been done before presenting the result and in case of no result show a message.

Here is a snippet of code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ffuuiw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I'd suggest using `BehaviorSubject` with boolean value and connect displaying spinner with value coming from `BehaviorSubject` by using `async` pipe in template. Problem is that in your example data is filtered almost immediately, so the spinner won't be visible.

Comment: Could you please help with a sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` to do that.

Inside `app.component.ts`:

define bs on beginning

```
loader$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

then modify your `filteredQuery` func

```
filteredQuery() {
    this.loader$.next(true);
    if (this.radioSelected === undefined) {
      this.loader$.next(false);
      return this.query;
    } else {
      this.loader$.next(false);
      return this.query.filter(
        q => parseInt(q.queryStatus.id) === this.radioSelected
      );
    }
  }
```

Then you need to apply changes in template:

```
...
<tbody>
    <div *ngIf="loader$ | async" class="loader">
        loader
    </div>
    <tr *ngFor="let queryDetails of filteredQuery()">
    ...
```

Only thing left would be to style your loader somehow. I'd suggest you to change displaying your array too, as you shouldn't execute functions inside your template, because it affects performance of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code I have add my loader div inside table and bind my function in radio button.
Once click on radio button its show loader for 1 second.

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let queryStatusCheck of queryStatus">
    <input id="{{queryStatusCheck.denomination}}" [value]='queryStatusCheck.id' type="radio" name="queryStatusCheck" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected" (click)="radioBtnclicked()">
                    {{queryStatusCheck.denomination}}
    <label for="{{queryStatusCheck.denomination}}">
                    </label>
</div>
 
<div>

    <table style="position: relative;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="text-lg-center">Date</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-lg-center">Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let queryDetails of filteredQuery()">
                <td class="text-lg-center">{{ queryDetails.created }}</td>
                <td class="text-lg-center">
                    <a style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#queryModal">
                        {{ queryDetails.title }}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <div class="my-loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></div>
    </table>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  isLoading = false;
  
  ...


  radioBtnclicked() {
    // Show loader
    this.isLoading = true;

    // Add your logic here.
    // Once its done set "isLoading = false;" to hide loader.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, 1000);

  }

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter an Array is a **sync** action. So in you want Angular refresh the "view", you need say to Angular to do it

```
this.loading=true; //show the loading
setTimeout(()=>{    //after refresh the view..
   ...filter here...
   this.loading=false;  //hide the loading
})
```

But even you're using a laaaaaarge array, the time to filter is about a few milliseconds